# All occurrences of text between quotes (like * but for the whole text, not a single word)

Tags: vim

When I edit XML-files I sometimes want to jump to the next occurrence of text between quotes. For example, when my cursor is on `my.attr` in `attr="my.attr"` I want to jump to the next occurence of `my.attr`. I want to do it via some key combination (like `Shift + *` which is for words occurrences). Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a visual selection of the attribute value inside double quotes with `vi"`. Then, there are several plugins that implement the `*` command for visual mode (usually by overloading the `*` command), i.e. they search for the next occurrence of the selected text. One such plugin is my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

#### Related plugins

If you want to change *all* attribute values (without constructing a `:%s/` substitution), my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321) provides a `gc{motion}` and `{Visual}gc` command that does that.

Comment: I highly recommend the use of some kind of visual star plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in command mode type `/<exact pattern>` if any special character then escape the special character like `\`

```
For example In command mode /"my\.attr"
```

So only search the exact pattern. `N` or `n` to move forward and backward .

Comment: You do not have to escape `"` in a vim pattern, but `.` matches any single character so you should escape it:  `/"my\.attr"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would yank the text inside the quotes with `yi"` (only works if the opening and closing quotes are on the same line) and then `/<C-R>"`.  (The `<C-R>` means CTRL-R, not 5 characters.)

This gives you a chance to modify the pattern before submitting it; as @Kalanidhi pointed out, you may have to escape some special characters.  It uses the same `i"` text object as in @Ingo Karkat's answer.

If your text is short, then you can edit the command line with the arrow keys, but if it is long you may want to edit it in a command-line window with `<C-F>`.  (Alternatively, if you are thinking ahead, use `q/` instead of `/`.)

```
:help y
:help text-objects
:help c_CTRL-R
:help cmdline-editing
:help cmdline-window
```

Comment: I feel this is hand rolling a visual star plugin. Here is a quick visual star mapping: `xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>` that might be worth trying out. Visually select the text then press `*`.